# 0-1 Knapsack with additional restriction (colored items)?

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I'm working on this problem mostly out of curiosity in my downtime at work.

Imagine the normal 0-1 Knapsack problem, except all the items are either yellow, red, blue, or green, and due to your OCD you must have exactly 2 items of each color in your knapsack.  So instead of the normal items each item has 3 properties: Weight, Value, Color.

Is this even still a knapsack problem, or is it better define in some other way?

Comment: It is still a knapsack problem, just with additional constraints, which has the potential to make the tree of possible solutions to examine considerably larger (4X as large in your specific example). Although it also gives you the ability to quickly reject a bunch of possible solutions as well, so the net change in solvability/efficiency probably isn't easily quantified in the abstract case...

Answer (score 1):

I'll use `nCk` to represent "n choose k" for ease of typing. Since you must have exactly 2 items of each color, the number of feasible solutions is O(`nC2`), which is O(`n^2`). Each solution can be evaluated in polynomial time, so the problem is solvable in polynomial time as well. In other words, it's far simpler than a regular knapsack problem.