# Calculating an optimum set of rows given certain constraints in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, knapsack-problem

Sorry for the vague sounding title, but here's the set up:

I have a list of parts, each with a manufacturer, a cost, and a profit. I'll add a snippet, but this would be a long list (dozens of manufacturers, hundreds of parts).

```
Manufacturer    Part Name   Cost    Profit
Cohiba          Behike 54   10.95   5.05
Rocky Patel     Edge        13.99   8.01
Acid            Liquid      8.49    3.51
```

I have a code that samples each unique manufacturer to select one part at random for each, and then calculates the total sum cost and profit.

```
ind <- sapply (unique( data$Manufacturer ) , function(x)
  sample( which(data$Manufacturer==x) , 1 ) )

Sampler <- data[ ind, ]

sum(Sampler$Profit)

sum(SamplerX$Cost)
```

I feel like there has to be a smarter way to ask it to simply find the optimum list of one unique part per manufacturer to give me the highest profit for the lowest cost. Can anyone give me some insight?

Comment: How do you plan to decide to choose a part?  One option would be to always select the highest profit first, and then in the case of a tie choose the lower cost.  Or do you have a different heuristic in mind?

Comment: Right, the next step ahead for me is that I have a set budget for what the total cost can be. The actual part doesn't matter, and I guess the part is kind of the solution I want it to spit back at me. I'm trying to get it to give me which combination of unique parts will give me the maximum profit under my budget. Does that help answer your question?

Comment: You're really asking two questions, each of which is very non-trivial to answer.  Once you select an algorithm (part one), then you need R code to execute it (part two).  You might want to choose an algorithm and then update your question with it.

Comment: I guess what I want it to do is create a permutation of all combinations of one part from each unique manufacturer, and then find the maximum profit when the sum cost is under X value, then tell me what the combination of parts is that yielded that profit is.

Comment: This seems to be an instance of the knapsack problem (discrete optimization), and as @Tim said, it's far from trivial. You may want to look for the different approaches (algorithms) to solve it before trying to code a solution

Comment: Thanks @PavoDive, those keywords have helped me find the guides I need to better study this and figure things out. You've put me on the right track, which is a much better start than I had before.

Comment: Although this post doesn't provide a solution, at least we know is solvable in polynomial time. The problem is exactly the same (replace color with supplier), and for sure has been addressed somewhere else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481516/0-1-knapsack-with-additional-restriction-colored-items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness:

The knapsack problem is one where a robber wants to maximize the price of the stolen items, while keeping weight at or below his sack capacity.
The adagio package has a function to solve it.

```
library(adagio)
# create some random data:
set.seed(1)
weights <- sample(1:100,30,FALSE)
prices <- sample(1:10000,30,FALSE)

# find what is the total weight
sum(weights)
[1] 1383

# Solve the problem, allowing a capacity of about 10% the total weight:
a <- knapsack(w=weights, p=prices, cap=138)

# See what a returns:
a
$capacity
[1] 138

$profit
[1] 50928

$indices
[1]  1  5 10 11 12 19 22 27

# validate results:
sum(weights[a$indices])
[1] 138
```

Please keep in mind that you'll need a lot of capacity if your vectors are large.

**####### EDIT TO ADD #######**

Considering that you want to maximize profit while keeping cost below certain limit, **AND** not exceeding more than certain number of manufacturers (one, in your question), this is a two-dimensional knapsack problem, for which I didn't find any function or package that solves it.

Alternatives:

1. Code it yourself: a good start would be `adagio::knapsack` (without the parenthesis, so you can see the code), and googling "two dimensional knapsack". There are plenty of algorithms in pseudo-code so you won't start from a blank sheet.
2. A workaround: If your output vector isn't really large, you could use `adagio::knapsack()` *disregarding manufacturer* and find a near-solution. Then you'll have to manually find wich manufacturers are duplicated in the result vector, and then find an item that is as close as possible *below* the cost of the item to replace and that belongs to a different, not-yet-used manufactor, with the highest profit possible. **Please notice** that this won't necessarily yield the best available solution, i.e., an optimum (the problem is NP-hard, so anyway it probably wouldn't), but it would be a good approximation.

Comment: May I contact you to help clarify a few questions I have on modifying this? You're right that this is a very complex problem, and I need help focusing my ideas before I try to ask another question for code help.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, you may consider marking with as accepted with the tick mark just below the downvoting button.

Answer (score 0):

I have to give full credit to PavoDive for helping me solve this. His use of the phrase "Knapsack Problem" is what got my head spinning, as I hadn't heard a version of the knapsack riddle since middle school.

Once he said that, I was able to quickly connect the dots and actually found that a package exists already to solve Knapsack problems with this exact setup:

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/adagio/docs/knapsack

The answer I needed is right there. Sharing this in case anyone else ever needs to solve this problem.